# Check if file exists in a directory specified by regex Linux

Tags: regex, linux, shell, unix

I'm trying to use regex inside a file operator to seek for a file where one subdirectory is specified with a regex, but I wonder if it's even possible. I think I tried all the quote and bracket combinations possible. Either I'm missing something here, or a file operator requires a specific path?

I'm not entirely sure. Could somebody please clarify?

What I want to achieve is something like this (this obviously doesn't work because it takes the regex part as name of the subdirectory)

```
if [[ -r '/agent/[0-9 .]*/bin/run.sh' ]]
```

Comment: Could you give concrete examples for the name of the variable subdirectory? So that we can check with the regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*find* has a `-regex` option

> -regex pattern
>
> File name matches regular expression pattern.  This is a match on the whole path, not a search.  For example, to match a file
>   named `./fubar3', you can use  the  regular  expression`.*bar.'  or 
>   `.*b.*3`,  but  not `f.*r3`. The regular expressions understood by find are by default Emacs Regular Expressions, but this can be changed with the
>   -regextype option.

```
if find . -regex '/agent/[0-9 \.]*/bin/run.sh'
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [manual](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression), only the **=~** operator does regex matching.

There's another way though:

```
RUNFILES=$( find /agent -name run.sh | grep -e '^/agent/[0-9 .]*/bin/run.sh$' )
if [ -n "$RUNFILES" ]
then
[...]
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for the worked out example. Yours and @pacholik's are both good answers. First answer does it in 1 line though, so will base best answer on that. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `ls` command with a regular expression:

```
if ls /agent/[0-9\ .]*/bin/run.sh
```

Comment: Seems the regex part is also taken as part of the stringset in this case as well.